# "to like because of" or "to like for"

Tags: word-choice

Should I use "for" or "because of" here?

> Once he told me that he has been to Japan and Korea and that he likes
>   Korea way more **for** the Korean spicy kimchi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a common English expression which looks superficially very similar

> I'm only here for the beer

Your sentence seems to follow the same pattern, but somehow doesn't seem right. I think that it's a matter of sentence construction rather than whether you can use **for** in this context- possibly the definite article **the** doesn't sound right. If you change it like this, **for** sounds fine:

> Once he told me that he has been to Japan and Korea and that he likes Korea way more for its spicy kimchi.

If you want to keep the sentence as it is, then **because of** works better:

> Once he told me that he has been to Japan and Korea and that he likes Korea way more **because of** the Korean spicy kimchi.